# Ubuntu 20.04 TP Link wireless usb WiFi keeps disconnecting and asking for password

Tags: wireless, tp-link

I ran "sudo lshw -C network" and got the following. Wifi keeps disconnecting and asking for password. I have an external TPLink usb wifi extender to connect to my router. Desktop pc.

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: 24:4b:fe:d0:7e:91
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:24 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f6504000-f6504fff memory:f6500000-f6503fff

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlx64700225d99d
       serial: 64:70:02:25:d9:9d
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=5.4.0-56-generic firmware=1.4 ip=192.168.1.6 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

dmesg | grep wlx:

```
[    5.319760] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0 wlx64700225d99d: renamed from wlan0
[    6.855627] wlx64700225d99d: authenticate with e0:0e:e4:6b:e1:f6
[    7.030365] wlx64700225d99d: send auth to e0:0e:e4:6b:e1:f6 (try 1/3)
[    7.031901] wlx64700225d99d: authenticated
[    7.033420] wlx64700225d99d: associate with e0:0e:e4:6b:e1:f6 (try 1/3)
[    7.037117] wlx64700225d99d: RX AssocResp from e0:0e:e4:6b:e1:f6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=12)
[    7.042967] wlx64700225d99d: associated
[    7.054642] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx64700225d99d: link becomes ready
[29943.834024] wlx64700225d99d: deauthenticating from e0:0e:e4:6b:e1:f6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

It goes on like above a numerous repetition

nmcli device wifi list:

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  B>
        E0:0E:E4:6B:E1:F9  COSMOTE WiFi Fon  Infra  5     270 Mbit/s  55      ▂>
*       E0:0E:E4:6B:E1:F6  --                Infra  5     270 Mbit/s  54      ▂>
*       E0:0E:E4:6B:E1:F6  W1nd              Infra  5     270 Mbit/s  52      ▂>
        24:58:6E:BB:C5:67  Nova-rJrkc        Infra  2     270 Mbit/s  44      ▂>
        E4:8D:8C:78:9B:1A  --                Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   35      ▂>
        C4:AD:34:5C:7B:81  Jenifer           Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  34      ▂>
        7C:39:53:CE:18:80  CYTA1880          Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  24      ▂>
        C4:A3:66:45:FC:76  COSMOTE-45FC76    Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  24      ▂>
        3C:98:72:C1:72:19  COSMOTE WiFi Fon  Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  12      ▂>
        78:B2:13:0C:18:09  COSMOTE WiFi Fon  Infra  5     270 Mbit/s  12      ▂>
        3C:98:72:C1:72:16  COSMOTE-376870    Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  10      ▂
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `dmesg | grep wlx` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you I will do. I tried the following sudo -i
echo "blacklist ath9k" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r ath9k
exit and so far I have had no disconnection but I have not restarted the pc. I will do so and then type those terminal commands. I tried to close the terminal but says there is a process running in this terminal.

Comment: *ath9k* is a driver for a completely different PCI, not USB, device. I doubt that it was loaded and possibly conflicting in any way. Miracles, however, are possible.

Comment: description: Wireless interface driver=ath9k_htc Let's hope when I restart the PC everything is ok.

Comment: *ath9k_htc* and *ath9k* are two differnt drivers for different devices. Bill Jones is not the same a Bill Smith.

Comment: I know. I did it with ath9k_htc as well. Is there a command to check for which device is the ath9k driver?

Comment: `modinfo ath9k` shows the PCI device IDs that use that driver. On the other hand, `modinfo ath9k_htc` shows the USB IDs that use that driver. *ath9k*, the PCI driver, shouldn't be any factor here in any way.

Comment: From `nmcli device wifi list`, we see that your device is appareently connected to *both* the router Wind and the repeater whos SSID is hidden. How is it that they have the same MAC address? MAC address cloning? I think you'd be better off without it, locking on the the strongest of the two by referencing its unique MAC address. Also, I think you'll have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11.

Comment: The Wind is the name of the hidden network/router I am connected... Basic settings for the WLAN

Switch on the WLAN in the 2.4 GHz frequency band

Switch on the WLAN in the 5 GHz frequency band the 2.4 is the F6 thee 5 ghz is the FB

Comment: I ran an lsmod but there was no ath9k there was ath9k_htc and ath9k_common.

Comment: "Basic settings for the WLAN Switch on the WLAN in the 2.4 GHz frequency band Switch on the WLAN in the 5 GHz frequency band the 2.4 is the F6 thee 5 ghz is the FB" I don't understand this at all. Sorry.

Comment: The WLAN has 2 Frequency bands with different mac addresses but in the WiFi list I see only the 2.4ghz band. Anyway I will restart pc and look it's fixed and report back. So far no disconnection. I don't know if there may be anything else interfering and creating the disconnections. I am sure the TPLink extender is not cooperating well with Ubuntu etc. Anyway thanks again.